# Question about gas grill flame issues -- on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have a gas grill where the flame is strong and the right color but sputters and puffs randomly.  I suspect asking for advice on what's wrong would be off-topic since it's not really cooking-related... but I could be wrong.

If it's not on-topic, can you suggest an SE site where it might be?

Answer (score 9):

We do equipment questions here, so I think the question you mean will be on-topic. Some equipment questions don't fare that well here, but it is mostly ones which are way too model specific for anybody but the manufacturer to say something about them. A common problem of grills should be OK - just ask it.

Comment: FWIW, +1. Just ask the question, @JimGarrison. If there are problems with the question, we can smooth them out.

Answer (score 2):

Even if it is on topic, you can also take a look at the SE [home improvement](http://diy.stackexchange.com) site to see if there's any gas appliance knowledge there.

Comment: Good idea regarding Home Improvement stack. I have a vague memory that "grill gas puffing" is a common Q.